# iOS - not working NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I have 2 functions in my app, that are using `NSURLConnection`. First one is for backup data to server, second for restore.

Problem is, when I run backup function as first one and after finishing backup I run the restore one, restore don't get any data back, but when I run restore as a first one and backup as second one, everything works fine.

Here are my codes:

**Backup**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

                    //setings values forHTTPHeaderField ...

                [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[jsonString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

                [request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


                NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

                [conn scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

                [conn start];
```

And than is this function - **Restore**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

                [request1 setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

                NSURLResponse *response;

                NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:&response error:nil];

                NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:oResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                NSLog(@"jsonData: %@", responseString);
```

oResponseData are (null)...

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't notice, that your Backup Request is asynchronous and start the restore before the backup is finished?

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It solves that problem...

Answer (score 0):

Problem was only in one thing as Claus Bönnhoff said in the comments. One connection was asynchronus and second synchronus...

When I set both NSURLConnections to synchronus, it works like a charm now!

Thanks to him again.